# interactive div sizing

Tags: jquery, animation, html, repeat

Okay this question is a little strange and hard to explain so i will give it a shot the idea seemed easy enough

One click anywhere on a div and the div width goes from 450 to 1400px hides two other divs on the page and adds a img to click to close it in the top right corner. Done.

Now click the img and the div resizes to 450px and those other divs come back and closing img hides. Done.

My  problem is after i click the img. its resizes and then returns back to the 1400px and hides the other 2 divs that are starting to show again. i don't want it to go back to the div click event.

here is the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".close").hide();
 $("#leftdiv").click(function(){

  $("#leftdiv").animate({
   width: "1400px",
   height: "450px"
    },1000);
    $("#middlediv, #rightdiv").hide(500);
    $(".close").show(500);

$("#leftdiv").css({"-webkit-animation":"bounce 0s 0s"});

});

$("#leftdiv .close").click(function(){
    $("#leftdiv").stop().animate({
        width: "450px",
        height: "450px"
    },1000);
$(".close").hide();
       $("#middlediv, #rightdiv").show(500);
       });    
   });
```

I'm trying to learn jquery i have only done html css before so i am trying to wrap my brain around it would love to know how to do Jquery

Comment: could my css3 animation be effecting my img click event at all?

Comment: I did a temp fix by giving the img a dblclick i still have to play with it to get it right but now i feel like i am headed in the right direction

Comment: okay so what i found was i had to move the close"button" outside of the div for this to work correctly. I will be readying more jquery tuts and watching more videos. anyone know of a good place i am using Tree House, jquery Docs and w3schools

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go with something like this, essentially adding and removing the click handlers when they're not needed.

```
$("#leftdiv").on('click', leftDivClickHandler);

function leftDivClickHandler(event)
{
    $("#leftdiv").off('click', leftDivClickHandler);

    $("#leftdiv").animate({
        width: "1400px",
        height: "450px"
    },1000, function() {
        $("#leftdiv .close").on('click', closeDiv);
    });
    $("#middlediv, #rightdiv").hide(500);
    $(".close").show(500);

    $("#leftdiv").css({"-webkit-animation":"bounce 0s 0s"});

  });
  event.preventDefault();
}

function closeDiv(event) 
{
    $("#leftdiv .close").off('click', closeDiv);

    $("#leftdiv").stop().animate({
        width: "450px",
        height: "450px"
    },1000, function() {
         $("#leftdiv").on('click', leftDivClickHandler);
    });

    $(".close").hide();
    $("#middlediv, #rightdiv").show(500);

    event.preventDefault();
}
```